# How ignore duplicate rows when insert

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, hibernate, jpa

I use `hibernate-jpa-2.1-api`. And I need some functionality.

I parse a file every minute and insert data into MSSQL DB. I need to skip duplicate rows. For example at `12:00` I've got in my file 300 rows. I parse every of them and insert 300 rows. After one minute (`12:01`) my file contains 500 rows. I parse it and I want to insert only the 200 new rows and not the old 300 rows.

In the old realization of the program I used SQL insert and did not use ORM.

Here is my old SQL query:

```
insert /*+ ignore_row_on_dupkey_index(avaya_cm_cdr, i_avaya_cm_cdr_nodub) */  into avaya_cm_cdr(acmcdr_id, cdrdate, cdrtime, secdur, condcode, attdconsole, codeused, outcrtid, codedial, dialednum, intrkcode, incrtid, callingnum, vdn, bcc, ppm, acctcode, authcode) values(seq_acmcdr_id.nextval, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

And here is my new insert with ORM:

```
em = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("COLIBRI").createEntityManager();
public void insertAVAYAcmCDRs(List<AvayaCmCdr> cdrList) {
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    for (AvayaCmCdr aCdrList : cdrList) {
        em.persist(aCdrList);
    }
    em.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

How can I use the analog to the function `ignore_row_on_dupkey_index` with ORM?

p.s. In the old realization I've used an Oracle DB.

Comment: What's wrong with the (russian) answer you've just got [here](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/470631/Аналог-функции-ignore-row-on-dupkey-index-в-mssqlили-ОРМ-hibernate)?

Answer (score 1):

*Database style option*

Hibernate does not offer to add an option to its `insert into` statements. And I don't know if the same option is available for MS SQL.

But if you find such an option, you can intercept the insert statement and add that yourself:

```
public class IgnoreRowOnDupInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {

  public String onPrepareStatement(String sql) {
    if (sql.startsWith("insert into avaya_cm_cdr") {
      return sql.replace("insert into", 
        "insert /*+ ignore_row_on_dupkey_index(avaya_cm_cdr, i_avaya_cm_cdr_nodub) */ into");
    }
    return sql;
  }

}
```

You need to declare this interceptor in your `persistence.xml`:

```
<property name="hibernate.ejb.interceptor" value="...IgnoreRowOnDupInterceptor" />
```

*JPA style option*

You could remember the last line from the last parsing (or retrieve it from the database) and skip the file until that line. In that case you even would save the time to parse every existing item again and again.

From my point of view this is the JPA way, because you usually use the database only as storage and keep the business logic in the (Java) application.