# How skip duplicate rows when insert data with JPA hibernate?

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jpa

I have method for insert data to MSSQL DB:

```
public void insertAVAYAcmCDRs(List<AvayaCmCdr> cdrList) {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        for (AvayaCmCdr aCdrList : cdrList) {
                em.persist(aCdrList);
            }
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.clear();
    }
```

I have duplicate objects in `List<AvayaCmCdr> cdrList` and I want skip insert it. For example my cdrList = 100 different objects. And I insert it to DB. After that my cdrList change and became contain 150 different objects but 100 objects is already in the database  and 50 objects is not. How can I insert only 50 objects to DB? This operation repeat each minute.... my ArrayList increases...

To better understand clarified. The ArrayList is formed from a file which is constantly increasing. I was floating it every minute. There are many files. When one is filled with 5,000 lines, a new, etc.

this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33995069/how-ignore-dublicate-rows-when-insert) not duplicate. I need insert to MSSQL

Comment: What it your primary key? In general, hibernate will check and skip those row if the pk is duplicated. And why not just remove those data in the file if it is already saved to the DB.

Comment: Yes in the your link my quation too. It not helped. This ansver for Oracle

Comment: This file create another system. I am only get it from FTP

Comment: Well you presumably did not get an answer (meeting your satisfaction) to your identical question because it is UNCLEAR, just as this one is UNCLEAR.

Comment: @user5620472 And it would be nice to get feedback to answers, either by voting, accepting or by a comment for clarification...